# How can I connect and get facebook profile information from a director apps (.dcr not .swf)?

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, adobe-director

We currently have a director apps (.dcr not .swf) that we want to integrate with the facebook api. 
(to connect via facebook, to challenge facebook friend from within the game)

Can I embedded a flash in the director apps that take care of connecting to Facebook ?

From what I saw from my search it seem that most of the tutorial or answer to mix director and flash were ask in 2004 and that director only support Action Script 2.

Is there a way to use action script 3 within a apps built in Director 11.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

I was a long time use of Director before switching to Flash and the whole web hoopla few years back. AFAIR, the Director-Flash bridge is terrible to work with, mainly due to the architecture of Director. Macromedia had done its bit to make the twain work together, but it wasn't enough. With the lesser relevance of Director in Adobe's software ecosystem, it's likely to be a pain at least and a disaster at worst.

Director does have an OK networking API (no SSL, IIRC) and it might be easier to whip up a few scripts to connect to FB. If Director doesn't support SSL and you need it, you can route your connections through a regular connection to your own servers, which then forward the request over SSL to FB and return the response.

If you're especially sadistic, you can write your own Xtra to do this. But if it's a one-off project, then it's obviously not worth it.

Not many more choices there, I'm afraid.

.p